# Writing my own audio player, where to start

Tags: c#, audio

I am reverse engineering some old DOS games I found lying around. I quickly realized that many of the files were just really old formats (well, maybe not that old. 20 years?) Many of the audio files were built using something based on Creative's technologies at that time. The format in question is described in detail at http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Creative_Voice.

What kinds of things can I use to help me write an application to play these audio files? For example is there a library that allows me to just feed in data and then let it determine what to do with the data?

I would like to write it as a C# application and then use the player for other old audio formats.

Comment: See this related Stack Overflow question as well: [Writing an audio player in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701240/writing-an-audio-player-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some more research.  Specifically, look at the data bytes.  Those will be codec-encoded.  So in addition to the CV decoder you will need to write ~8 codec decoders.

These may help

http://csharpsynthproject.codeplex.com

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dawate/archive/2009/06/24/intro-to-audio-programming-part-3-synthesizing-simple-wave-audio-using-c.aspx

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Generating-Sound-Waves-with-C-Wave-Oscillators

Comment: Is there something that I can use so that I don't have to worry about writing an audio player, but only focus on the decoders?